# MUTATION_REQ/RSP message keep being dropped by Cassandra Cluster

Tags: cassandra

I have a Cassandra cluster on my development environment. Recently I did some write request testing, and found many "MUTATION_REQ/RSP was dropped" message from the log as follows.

`${source_ip}:7000->/${dest_ip}:7000-SMALL_MESSAGES-d21c2c3e dropping message of type MUTATION_RSP whose timeout expired before reaching the network`

`MUTATION_REQ messages were dropped in last 5000 ms: 0 internal and 110 cross node. Mean internal dropped latency: 0 ms and Mean cross-node dropped latency: 3971 ms`

I also found there were more dropped MUTATION_REQ than MUTATION_RSP:
(I found that with "nodetool tpstats")

```
Latencies waiting in queue (micros) per dropped message types
Message type Dropped 50% 95% 99% Max

HINT_RSP 63 1131.752 2816.159 3379.391 3379.391
GOSSIP_DIGEST_SYN 0 1629.722 2816.159 4055.2690000000002 4055.2690000000002
HINT_REQ 4903 1955.666 1955.666 1955.666 1955.666
GOSSIP_DIGEST_ACK2 0 1131.752 2816.159 4055.2690000000002 4055.2690000000002
MUTATION_RSP **6146** 1358.102 2816.159 3379.391 89970.66
MUTATION_REQ **450775** 1358.102 3379.391 4866.323 4139110.981
```

My questions are:

1. **Is it usual for a health cluster to have so many dropped MUTATION_REQ/RSP?**
2. **I supposed MUTATION_RSP were dropped on replica node, and MUTATION_REQ on coordinator node. am I correct?**

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I had same issues and asked same question on Cassandra mailing list, here answer:

> First thing to check, do you have NTP client running on all Cassandra
> servers? Are their clock in sync? If you answer "yes" to both, check
> the server load, does any server have high CPU usage or disk
> utilization? Any swapping activity? If not, check the GC logs, and
> looking for long GC pauses.

Mine issue was wrong clock synchronization.

So, first things first, check clock on each node with `timedatectl` utility, in output you should have two entries `NTP enabled` and `NTP synchronized` with `yes`. In case clock out of sync, force synchronization on all nodes and then make full repair on each affected node (I made `nodetool -full -pr`). After that you should radically less messages with MUTATION_* drops - from hundreds on heavy load to one-two per day.

Comment: Do you still have that thread? I'm curious to see how they linked the dropped messages to the lack of sync in NTP.

Answer (score 1):

Increase concurrent read/write (cassandra.yaml) to 64 (default 32)

```
concurrent_reads: 64
concurrent_writes: 64
concurrent_counter_writes: 64
```